# What would be "pick up the phone" icon in the future?

Tags: futurology

What would be "pick up the phone" icon in the future when there will be really few stationary phones? Image of green phone handset would look strange for people who have never seen landline. Maybe there is an example of such transformation with icons of retired stuff nowadays that can help to make a guess.

Comment: You are assuming we will have actual phones in the future.  All communications are becoming one.

Comment: @bowlturner, good point! it'll be literally embedded.

Comment: I think this might be a good question to ask on [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). There's [a similar question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/3117/5538) about the usage of the floppy disk icon to mean save, and this is already something that has essentially gone by the wayside. [Patrick's answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/3119/5538) points out that the icon is no longer a metaphor, but an idiom.

Comment: @JYelton, the question is about possible transformation in the future. And not about the stuff I'm dealing with now as user and want to improve my experience of using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I still see the floppy disk icon used to represent save:

[image: Save]

Even though Floppy disks haven't been used in years. The icon has now taken on a meaning beyond that which it originally represented.

The phone icon has now grown to a similar status, how many phones have you seen (even home phones) that look anything like this?

[image: Phone]

The icon now exists with a meaning of its own, that is getting steadily more and more abstracted away from the thing it originally represented. So in the future a phone symbol will still be used to represent a phone, it may get simplified or stylized further but it's already pretty simple so even that is unlikely. The save icon is definitely likely to have that happen though.

Comment: THANK you! I had been totally sure I knew at least one technically totally obsolete icon... and didn't even figure out which it was when clicking the thing in an unrelated task ^^.

Comment: I have noticed that some programs have a hard disc icon for "save" instead of the floppy disc, but the latter is still by far the most common

Comment: @Pyritie One reason not to use a hard disk icon is a lot of computer users have no idea what a hard disk looks like. A floppy disk everyone used to know what it looks like although I've not even seen one in over 10 years...

Comment: @TimB Would younger people know what a floppy disc looked like unless we used it as the save icon? I'm sure there are plenty of people who don't know what a cassette tape or VCR look like either. Though now I'm curious - if you showed that save icon to some kids, would they tell you that it's a floppy disc or that it's "the save button"?

Comment: @Pyritie The floppy disk icon started from an instantly recognizable (at the time) product but has since moved on past it. The hard drive was never instantly recognizable so was always a bad choice. The "floppy disk" save icon can now be said to stand on its own. As you say that would be an interesting study to see the results of. I expect you're right that they'd tell you it's the save button.

Comment: @Pyritie "Wow! 3D printed save button!"

Comment: Coming across this answer made me think of the [ux.se] question [Save icon, is the floppy disk icon dead?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/3117/7062).

Answer (score 1):

As it already is today, it will be a picture of the person who is calling you.

Comment: There is also an icon with handset below this picture on my cell which is used to accept the call

Comment: Oops.  didn't think of phones that still have physical buttons.  For screen rendered buttons, I would prefer a picture of the caller surrounded by a green border, with alternative options rendered as buttons to the right or below.  In that scenario, the alternative options would include ignore, send-to-voicemail and send-callback-text, each with appropriate icons.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the analogy of accepting a connection. So maybe some sort of green connected chain, or just a green tick signifying that you permit the connection to be created.

The hang-up button would of course in that case either be a red cross (not a fan, personally, due to the many other connotations,) or a broken red chain indicating that the connection is severed.

On second thought, by this point in time we'd be so used to the position and function of said button that we might not need an icon at all, unless the form factor of our phones has changed significantly.

Comment: There definitly should be some kind of simplification. Green tick is a good idea, not sure about chain (never seen it in connection phone/internet visualization)

Comment: I've never seen a chain icon used either but it seemed like a simple way to communicate the idea. What I have seen is a pair of connected or disabled cables in my network manager (a Linux one,) which wouldn't really make sense in a wireless context.

What it really comes down to though is that, without the analogy of "picking up the phone" what we're doing when we answer the call is accepting it, so the tick fits well with that. I just don't like the red cross used for "hanging up", since at that point you've already accepted, there's no rejection..